# How to fetch all the rows based on conditions greater than or lesser then?

Tags: mysql, html

I am still learning MySQL queries and am stuck with this one. I have a database of `EMPLOYEE`. It contains one table `EMP_INFO`. It has on field named `SALARY`. In my HTML form I have 2 text fields to enter `SALARY`. I want to fetch all the employee's information from my `EMP_INFO` table whose salary comes within the entered salary limits.

Comment: SELECT * FROM EMP_INFO WHERE SALARY BETWEEN ? AND ?

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response. This code is working. Can I've a query for MySql where I can check the details of all the employee based on greater(>) or lesser(<) than condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query...

`select * from EMP_INFO where salary between 10000 AND 25000`

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form looks like this:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="salary[min]" />
  <input type="text" name="salary[max]" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The your result.php could look like this:

```
$min = (int)$_POST['salary']['min'];
$max = (int)$_POST['salary']['max'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE salary BETWEEN {$min} AND {$max}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE salary > {$min} AND salary < {$max}
```

OR

```
select * from EMP_INFO where salary between {$min} AND {$max}
```

Pass min ,max values from your script.

Comment: WoW!!! You guys are awesome... You all are so quick and this website is very fast... I must appreciate it... This problem is solved... Now m moving ahead with little complex query... once I stuck;ll be back over here... Thanks guys... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_INFO WHERE SALARY BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE salary > {$min} AND salary < {$max}
```

This way you can use greater than and less than.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this `>=` and `<=` if you want select inclusively:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE salary >= {$min} AND salary <= {$max};
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE salary Between {$min} AND  {$max};
```